# Run terminal command (python command) at start up

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts

New to Ubuntu, but have looked everywhere to get this question answered. Found no solution so far. Basically I need to run two terminal commands on startup, which follow each other directly. This will allow me to open a python script on start up. The script works when opened manually, but I'm at a loss to get it to work on boot. In terminal I type:

```
cd /directory/with/python/script/
python name.py
```

The script works, but I'm having trouble getting it to run on boot.

Comment: Any reason why you can't run `python /directory/with/python/script/name.py` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you wish to run this script every time your machine boots, a convenient way is to add an upstart init task.

Create a file `my-startup-script.conf` (its name is up to you, but it must have extension `.conf`) in `/etc/init`, containing the following:

```
description "Describe what the script does."
start on filesystem
task
script
    cd /path/to/script
    python name.py
end script
```

Note that your script will run with root privileges.

Comment: Consider using a [session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job) (as Upstart calls it), so that it will run as OP's user.