# pulseaudio command in a .conf file inside etc/init not running at start up

Tags: command-line, scripts, pulseaudio

Following the post here [Run terminal command (python command) at start up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516149/run-terminal-command-python-command-at-start-up?newreg=ef6e2d42051944ba8a90f87d3bbf1fc4) I created a .conf file in etc/init folder with the following content.

```
description "initializes audio"
start on filesystem
task
script
    pulseaudio -D
    exit
end script
```

I use the root account in Ubuntu 16.04. Generally at start up the audio icon on the notification tray is muted and the command $ pulseaudio -D unmutes it.

However .conf doesn't seems to function as it should. I still see the audio icon muted have to manually type in the command in the terminal.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) explains a lot of other ways to run scripts at start up, including the one I am using, but I need to know what is going wrong with my current method. So I would appreciate answers correcting my method rather than explaining other ways to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Ubuntu 16.04, a systemd operating system.  Upstart mechanisms do not work on it.  Write a systemd service unit, not an upstart job file.  And (hint!) don't try to "dæmonize" that which is *already dæmonized*.

### Further reading

- https://askubuntu.com/a/707750/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/780747/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/613785/43344
- https://askubuntu.com/a/617822/43344
- [Rationale for switching from upstart to systemd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/613366/43344)